# Read Check Box Value from JQuery Datatable header

Tags: checkbox, header, datatables

I am creating a HTML table dynamically and in the table header columns I have check boxes and text.Some check boxes are checked on initial load and some are not checked. After that I am applying datatable plugin on my HTML table. But When I check or un-check some of the check boxes in the header and try to read the new values I always get the original value of the check box while it was created.

Below is how I am reading the column check box values

```js
var columns = $('#myTable').dataTable().dataTableSettings[0].aoColumns;
$.each(columns, function (i, v) {
    var object = jQuery.parseHTML(v.sTitle);//innerHTML of input type='checkbox'
    if (object != null) {
        chkbox = object[0]; //object[1] is Text
        isChecked=chkbox.checked;
    }
});
```

**EDIT**
My HTML for checked and not checked check boxes on initial load

For Checked Check Box

```html
<input style='margin-right:5px' onclick=EnableDisableColumn(this); id='" + id+ "'     **checked='checked'** type='checkbox' Value='" + value + "' name='" + name+ "' />"
```

For Un -Checked Check Box

```html
<input style='margin-right:5px' onclick=EnableDisableColumn(this); id='" + id+ "'      type='checkbox' Value='" + value + "' name='" + name+ "' />"
```

Comment: You should have your `onclick=` quoted, eg `onclick=".."`

Comment: I have onclik method as well I pass "this" to that method and that works fine. Its only When I click on "Save" button on my page and try to read the checkboxes.

Comment: It is an general advice, has nothing to do with the functionality you are trying to do or the question in general, except the onclicks may be broken in some browsers, and it certainly not will pass a validator test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dataTables does not respond to changes in the DOM, and magically updates its internal variables when a checkbox is checked. dataTables return in any case the content of `<th>`'s as it was when the table was initialized. Seen from a dataTables point of view, the content of the `<th>` is just a peice of plain text.

Why go around dataTables anyway? The headers and the checkboxes are fully accessible in javascript or jQuery as always, with our without dataTables.

Here is an example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/XTpKH/**

```js
var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable();

$('th').click(function() {
    var msg = 'this header checkbox is ';
    msg += $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked') ? ' ' : 'not ';
    msg +='checked'
    alert(msg);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need data table to fix my header and first column of the table.

Comment: dataTables to fix what? the above does not click with datatables at all, no matter what you want imagine dataTables to do.

Comment: Using datatable to extend my HTML table so when I scroll vertically and horizontally my table header and First column of the table remain fixed.

Comment: have you ever clicked on the link / example / demo in my answer?